# website with pretty permalinks except pagination

Tags: customization, url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules

I use friendly URLs on my wordpress page so I have for example shop/page/2 I would like to have It like shop/?paged=2. Is there anything like rewriterules but opossite to it ;) ? Which converts pretty permalinks into "ugly" one?

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of using the settings tab of the dashboard? https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

Answer (score 2):

WP permalink handling is sort of layered. They underlying "ugly" permalinks capture the actual logic of the system and the "pretty" permalinks are just cosmetic enhancement on top of it.

Even when pretty permalinks are enabled, the original ugly permalinks *still* continue to work. But under normal circumstances they get redirected to a pretty version.

You could selectively kill pretty redirect with something like this:

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', function ( $redirect_url ) {

    if ( is_paged() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}, 10, 1 );
```

Though this won't affect how links are *generated*, so API functions which deal with pagination and stuff will still output pretty results. It's probably quite involved to override this comprehensively.

Comment: Thank you, so this makes me duplicate content, how to improve that ?

Comment: Well, implemented properly it shouldn't _be_ duplicate because it should redirect to one correct version of the page. If you do have duplicates they can and should be clarified with `canonical` tags.